# MS Access SQL Select Statement from Two Tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, vba, select-query

I have two Microsoft Access database tables.  They are named `Historical_Stock_Prices` and `Balance_Sheets`.  I need to combine data from each of these tables to create a table called `Daily`.  I need to take the fields `Ticker`, `[Date]`, and `[Close]` from `Historical_Stock_Prices` and I need to take the field `Common_Stocks` from `Balance_Sheets`.

I will not be taking every row from the `Historical_Stock_Prices` and `Balance_Sheets` though.  I will only be taking the rows that are on or before a date selected in a `DateTimePicker` named `dtpDateSelection`.

Now the main problem that I have is that `Historical_Stock_Prices` contains a row for each day.  While `Balance_Sheets` contains a row for each quarter.  So for each day in a quarter the figure `Common_Stocks` figure that comes from `Balance_Sheet` will be the same.

How do I do this?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Dim Date1 As Date = dtpDateSelection.Value
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Daily AS SELECT Ticker, [Date], [Close] From Historical_Stock_Prices WHERE [Date] = " & Date1 & "", con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This obviously does not incorporate the table `Balance_Sheet` at all.  Also, currently my where statement is throwing an error.

**Additional Information: Table Schema**

[image: Balance_Sheet Schema]

[image: Historical_Stock_Prices Schema]

Comment: How are Historical_Stock_Prices and Balance_Sheets linked together?  Do they have a primary/foreign key?  If they don't have a primary/foreign key then I am guessing they are linked via a Quarter and Year field.

Comment: @Linger They are not linked.  I'm not sure what the best way to link them is.  `Historical_Stock_Prices` has a primary key of two fields. They are `Ticker` and `[Date]`.  `Balance_Sheets` has a primary key of three fields.  They are `Ticker`, `[Year]` and `Period`.

Answer (score 2):

Inner join on the quarter that Historical_Stock_Prices and Balance_Sheets have in common.  That is, every date falls in a quarter.  If Balance_Sheets has a field named Period that is the number 1, 2, 3 or 4, corresponding to each quarter in a year, and you have a Year field that is a 4 digit number then this select query should work and can be easily converted into a make table query.

```
select Ticker, Date, Close, Common_Stocks
from Historical_Stock_Prices, Balance_Sheets
where Format(Historical_Stock_Prices.Date, "q") = Balance_Sheets.Period
      and Year(Historical_Stock_Prices.Date) = Balance_Sheets.Year
```

Comment: The suggested code returned this error message `Additional information: Cannot find table or constraint.`

Comment: Do you have a field in Balance_Sheets named Quarter or something equivalent to it? I see that you mentioned Year and Period fields above.  Does Period represent a quarter (e.g. have the value 1, 2, 3 or 4)?

Comment: I've changed `Balance_Sheets.Quarter` to `Balance_Sheets.Period` but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try this out. When I tested something like it in Access 2010 it didn't like the Format(...) in the inner join. So I've cross joined the tables (using a comma instead of the words inner join) and moved the on statement into a where clause. Also make sure all of the field and table names exist and are spelled correctly and that none of them have whitespace. If that doesn't work you'll need to post the schema of your two tables for us to review.

Comment: I have verified that all my field and table names exist and are spelled correctly.  I guess the next step is posting the schema of my two tables.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I have added the schema of my two tables to my original post.

Comment: Have you tried running the select query from within the Access database?  If it does not work, can you run a very simple query from within Access and from vb.net (e.g. `select * from Historical_Stock_Prices`)?

Comment: The whole Select query does not work withing Access.  `select * from Historical_Stock_Prices` and `select * from Balance_Sheets` does work.  I think one problem may be that in your answer `Date` and `Close` should be `[Date]` and `[Close]`

Comment: When I try this `select Historical_Stock_Prices.Ticker, [Date], [Close], Common_Stocks
from Historical_Stock_Prices, Balance_Sheets
where Format(Historical_Stock_Prices.[Date], "q") = Balance_Sheets.Period
      and [Year](Historical_Stock_Prices.[Date]) = Balance_Sheets.[Year]` within Access I do not get the `Snytax Error` message anymore.  I get this error message `Type mismatch in expression`

Comment: I think the `Type mismatch in expression` is because I'm trying to link the table using `Period` (as an integer) from `Balance_Sheets` to `[Date]` (as a date) from `Historical_Stock_Prices.

Comment: Looks like Access unhelpfully converted `Year(Historical_Stock_Prices.[Date])` to `[Year](Historical_Stock_Prices.[Date])`, which is causing it to try and reference the [Year] field instead of use the Year(...) method.  Replace `[Year](Historical_Stock_Prices.[Date])` with `Format(Historical_Stock_Prices.[Date], "yyyy")`.

Comment: I made the changes and I still get `Type mismatch in expression`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38564/discussion-between-jeremy-cook-and-gromit1)

Answer (score 2):

Create query off of Historical_Stock_Prices that includes 2 new fields, Quarter and Year, with the appropriate functions to pull those values from the date of the row.  Then join your two tables using those fields.  Your final statement in VB should go against that query.

As for why you are getting an error on the SQL statement, you do not have # around the parameter.

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Daily AS SELECT Ticker, [Date], [Close] From Historical_Stock_Prices WHERE [Date] = #" & Date1 & "#", con)
```

Note that this is still bad form, and is just waiting for SQL Injection attacks.  BEst to look up how to use parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will work on it.  I had previously tried using a paramaterized query but i was getting an error on that too.  Here is what I had:  `SELECT Ticker, [Date], [Close] From Historical_Stock_Prices WHERE [Date] = ?", con)  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Date1)`

Comment: It's usually better to use something like this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", OleDbType.Date).value = Date1`

Answer (score 2):

```
"SELECT [H].[Ticker], [H].[Date], [H].[Close], [B].[Common_Stocks] 
FROM [Historical_Stock_Prices] AS [H], [Balance_Sheets] AS [B] 
WHERE [H].[Ticker] = [B].[Ticker] 
AND Int(Format([H].[Date],'Q')) = Int([B].[Period]) 
AND Int(Year([H].[Date])) = Int([B].[Year]) 
AND [H].[Date] <= #" & Date1.value & "#"
```

Comment: The `Period` is numeric.  I got this error though `Additional information: Cannot find table or constraint.`

Comment: take out the `ON Year(H.Date) = B.Year` and `AND Format(H.Date,'Q') = B.Period` and change `AND H.Ticker = B.Ticker` to `ON H.Ticker = B.Ticker` and try it just to see if you get the same error

Comment: @nordeen1, are you sure you have a table called Historical_Stock_Prices?  Or is it "Historical Stock Prices"?

Comment: @Linger Yes.  The name of the table is Historical_Stock_Prices.

Comment: This error `Additional information: Cannot find table or constraint.` occurs when Access cannot find a table by the name you are using.  Check both of your table names for spelling, and that there are no blank spaces in it (including beginning and end)

Comment: Are you running the query as is, or are you creating a procedure with it?  Try running as a query without creating a procedure to see if it works

Comment: @APrough I have checked all of my table and field names for spelling and blank spaces and I haven't found any.

Comment: @Linger I was running a procedure with the query but I have since tried just running the query and got an error that way too.

Comment: Man, it should work as it is.  But, I edited my answer to try something else.  If it doesn't work check every field and table name closely to make sure they are correct.

Comment: @Linger Same error.  Someone suggested to try posting the schema of my two tables for review.  Any idea on the best way to do this?

Comment: Just open the tables up in design view and get a screneshot of them

Comment: @Linger I added brackets to some of the words to clear up some syntax errors I was getting.  Here is the new code: `SELECT H.Ticker, H.[Date], H.[Close], B.Common_Stock
FROM Historical_Stock_Prices AS H 
INNER JOIN Balance_Sheets AS B
ON [Year](H.[Date]) = B.[Year] 
AND Format(H.[Date],'Q') = B.Period
AND H.Ticker = B.Ticker
WHERE H.[Date] = #" & Date1 & "#"`. But I am still getting this error `Type mismatch in expression`

Comment: `B.Common_Stock` should have been `B.Common_Stocks`.  It looks like you missed the `s` on the end of the field name.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Linger I've changed to `B.Common_Stocks`.  I'm still getting this error `Type mismatch in expression`.

Comment: I changed the query to force the period and year to an integer

Comment: @Linger I'm getting `Syntax error` again.  I think it may have to do with words like `Year` and `Date` not being `[Year]` and `[Date]`

Comment: @Linger I think the `Type mismatch in expression` is because I'm trying to link the table using `Period` (as an integer) from `Balance_Sheets` to `[Date]` (as a date) from `Historical_Stock_Prices.

Comment: Actually in the above query the period and the result of the yaer function are being converted to Int.  I have modified the query again to force everything to convert to what is should be and added the brackets around all of the fields.

Comment: @Linger I don't get any errors in VB.net but when I view the table `Daily` there are no rows.  The columns are there but no data in the rows.

Comment: @Linger Any idea why there would be no rows?

Comment: Try the JOIN with just `CStr([H].[Ticker]) = CStr([B].[Ticker])` and you definitely should get rows.  Then add the Year part of the join and check.  Then add the period and check.  Find out where you are not getting any results.  You could also try the Year, Ticker, and Period in a WHERE clause instead of a join

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38563/discussion-between-linger-and-gromit1)